# Priority Queue Heap in Java

Tags: java, heap, priority-queue

I would like to understand Priority Queue heaps in Java syntax.

Min Heap

```
PriorityQueue<String> heap = new PriorityQueue<String>(
                (w1, w2) -> count.get(w1).equals(count.get(w2)) ?
                w2.compareTo(w1) : count.get(w1) - count.get(w2) );
```

Max Heap

```
PriorityQueue<String> heap = new PriorityQueue<String>(
                (w1, w2) -> count.get(w1).equals(count.get(w2)) ?
                w2.compareTo(w1) : count.get(w2) - count.get(w1) );
```

I see that the difference between the two pieces of code is whether w1 is subtracted from w2 or vice versa.

For example, if I have (1,2)

Min Heap:
(1,2) -> 1 - 2 : -1

Max Heap:
(1,2) -> 2 -1 : 1

Can someone explain to me the fundamental level of how the priority value is being set for each of the values beginning with what the (w1, w2) syntax means i.e. it represents the parameter for a function where w1 is a node preexisting in the tree and w2 represents the new value that is being added to the tree and the function executes w1 - w2 or w2 - w1 to determine the priority value.

If any clarification on the question is needed, let me know!

Edit:
From comments below, I now understand that (w1, w2) -> () is a lambda expression. Can anyone now explain the workings of the lambda expression with respect to priority queues with heaps in java? As in, does w1 represent a value existing in the queue and w2 the new value, and as such how the priority value is being set

Comment: Also, the () -> code looks a lot like JavaScript, any relation?

Comment: You should edit your question rather than posting a comment.

Comment: "beginning with what the (w1, w2) syntax means" This is a lambda expression. They are very similar to "fat arrow functions" in JavaScript.

Comment: w1 and w2 are just 2 different elements in the queue. I'm guessing they are maybe words from the var name. Your lambda function is just defining which one is less than the other (and so is placed closer to the front of the queue). This lambda seems to be getting the priority from some kind of count map.

Comment: It's called a lambda expression - it looks a lot like lambda expressions in most languages that have them.

Comment: Well I just learned that there is such a thing called Lambda expressions.. @Hitobat are you implying that a value in the queue is pulled and compared against the new value 'w2' to determine its priority value and thus where it lands in the queue?

Comment: Yes. You can think of the items in the queue as an ordered list (although it's actually a heap). When you add a new item, the queue needs to find the place where it sits in the list. It does this by comparing the items, using the comparison function you provide.

Comment: This code suffers from the fatal flaw of using subtraction in place of comparison. In the expression `result=A-B`, if A is sufficiently negative and B is sufficiently positive, the calculation will overflow and the function will incorrectly report that A > B. Subtraction is not comparison!

Comment: @Jim Mischel how would you go around that issue? I know with merge sort you have l+(r-l)/2 if this is the same case. Also, welcome to stackoverflow haha

Comment: You get around the issue by replacing `count.get(w1) - count.get(w2)` with `count.get(w1).compareTo(count.get(w2))`.

Comment: @JimMischel I must have misunderstood what you were saying. The compareto is for strings and the get represents a count in a map. I appreicate you letting me know about compareto though! Cheers.

Comment: You can call `compareTo` on Integers, too. The point here is that if the counts are equal, then you compare the strings for your result. If the counts aren't equal, you have to get the result of comparing them.

Comment: @JimMischel Hey Jim, I appreciate your help. It seems that you have a good grasp on all this and I am going to ask a new question on Lambda expressions. Would you mind taking a look at it when you have the time?